# How to use multiple parameters in $_POST

Tags: php, parameters

beginning programmer here so my apologies if this is a waste of your time.

I've made an HTML form which looks like this:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
    <label for="artist">Artist:</label><br>
    <input title="" type="text" name="artist" id="artist" value="Muse" required><br>
    <label for="album">Album:</label><br>
    <input title="" type="text" name="album" id="album" value="Live At Rome Olympic Stadium" required><br>
    <label for="genre">Genre:</label><br>
    <input title="" type="text" name="genre" id="genre" value="Rock" required><br>
    <label for="year">Year:</label><br>
    <input title="" type="number" name="year" id="year" value="2013" required><br>
    <label for="tracks">Tracks:</label><br>
    <input title="" type="number" name="tracks" id="tracks" value="13" required><br><br>
    <input title="" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The submitted information is sent to post.php, which looks like this:

```
if ($_POST['artist'] ['album'] ['genre'] ['year'] ['tracks']) {
    echo "The artist name is " . $_POST['artist'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The album name is " . $_POST['album'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The genre is " . $_POST['genre'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The year of release is " . $_POST['year'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The number of tracks is " . $_POST['tracks'];
    echo "<br>";
} else {
    echo "You have not filled out all the forms";
}
```

(I'm not sure wether or not to use isset - but that's a different matter)

According to my editor, PHPStorm, there's no errors in the formatting of the parameters in $_POST however my browser gives me the following errors:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'album' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php1\week2test\week2music\post.php on line 3

Warning: Illegal string offset 'genre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php1\week2test\week2music\post.php on line 3

Warning: Illegal string offset 'year' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php1\week2test\week2music\post.php on line 3

Warning: Illegal string offset 'tracks' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php1\week2test\week2music\post.php on line 3

How am I supposed to format my parameters in $_POST to rid these errors? Or if that's not the problem, then I don't know what the problem is, do you have some insight?

Should I be using isset in this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use post like that to test if they've been sent. Use isset if you want to achieve this. Should var dump to all your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if ($_POST['artist'] ['album'] ['genre'] ['year'] ['tracks'])` this doesn't exist in your current context, this will be a 5 depth array.

You meant `if ($_POST['artist'] && $_POST['album'] && $_POST['genre'] && $_POST['year'] && $_POST['tracks'])`

Or, even better, using `isset()` : `if (isset($_POST['artist']) && isset($_POST['album']) && isset($_POST['genre']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['tracks']))`

But I prefer using a sexier solution, storing in an array the keys of the `$_POST` I want to check, and then, loop over that array :

```
$KeysToCheck = array('artist', 'album', 'genre', 'year', 'tracks');
$AllFieldsAreGood = true;

foreach($KeysToCheck as $KeyToCheck)
    if (!isset($_POST[$KeyToCheck]))
        $AllFieldsAreGood = false;

if (!$AllFieldsAreGood)
    echo "You have not filled out all the forms";
else
{
    // success ! Manage it.
}
```

Take note that using `isset()` on a checkbox will be `true` only if the box is checked.

Comment: this indeed is what i meant, thank you Cid. is it recommended to use isset in this scenario?

Comment: Yes its better to use `isset` so that you don't loose out on values like 0/false if that is intentional and necessary.

Comment: Yep, as stated @RevanthM

Answer (score 1):

Using isset is better if you want to use non-NULL values received from POST

```
if (isset($_POST['artist'], $_POST['album'], $_POST['genre'], $_POST['year'], $_POST['tracks']))
```

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` is used to check that variable exists and it's not null.

Hence it's always preferred to use it. In your case it can be used like:

```
if (isset($_POST['artist']) && isset($_POST['album']) && isset($_POST['genre']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['tracks'])) {
    echo "The artist name is " . $_POST['artist'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The album name is " . $_POST['album'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The genre is " . $_POST['genre'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The year of release is " . $_POST['year'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The number of tracks is " . $_POST['tracks'];
    echo "<br>";
} else {
    echo "You have not filled out all the forms";
}
```